# Error in my Volley. I'm trying upload a image in my webserver

Tags: php, android, android-volley

```
E/Volley: [5836] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

This are my codes:

```
private ImageView imgNBI;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private String image, name, imgtype, retrieveDriverID,driverID;

private String KEY_DRIVERID = "driverid";
private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private String KEY_IMAGETYPE = "imgtype";
private String KEY_NAME = "name";
private Context ctx = this;

ProgressDialog pDialog;
Context context = this;

private String UPLOAD_URL ="http://angkas.net23.net/uploadimage1.php";
```

This is my code for update:

```
private void update() {
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();
getUser();
retrieveDriverID = driverID;
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Requirements_1.this, "This is response: "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Requirements_1.this, "This is error: "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        image = getStringImage(bitmap);
        String ddrid = retrieveDriverID;
        String drname = name;

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(KEY_DRIVERID, ddrid);
        if(ddrid != null){params.put(KEY_DRIVERID,ddrid);}
        params.put(KEY_IMAGETYPE, "NBIImg");
        params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
        if(image != null){params.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);}
        params.put(KEY_NAME, drname);
        if(drname != null){params.put(KEY_NAME,drname);}
        return params;
    }
};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

This is for when I click the imageView:

```
public void clicknbi(View view) {
showFileChooser("1");
}
private void showFileChooser(String request) {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
}
```

This is the Activity Result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
    Uri filePath = data.getData();
    try {
        //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
        //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
        imgNBI.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Converting image:

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
return encodedImage;
}
```

And this is my PHP:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$RegistrationDate = date('Y-m-d');
$driverid = $_POST['driverid'];
 $imgtype = $_POST['imgtype'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

require_once('dbcon.php');

$pathname = "$name$imgtype";

$path = "Images/$pathname.png";

$actualpath = "http://angkas.net23.net/$path";

//$sql = "INSERT INTO driverregistration     (DriverID,RegistrationDate,EnglishProficiency,TagalogProficiency,NBIImg) VALUES ('$driverid','$RegistrationDate','','','$actualpath');";

 $sql = "UPDATE driverregistration SET NBIImg = '$actualpath' WHERE DriverID = $driverid;";


if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
 file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
 echo "Successfully Registered";
}  
else
{
echo "Could not insert image";
}

}
else
{
 echo 'error';
  }
?>
```

I am encountering two errors. The first one is the null object reference and the second error is:

```
 java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

I'm getting this error in my Toast.

Comment: Is 'getStringImage' returning a string?

Comment: Please post full exception details - or, at a minimum, point out which lines are causing the exception. Also, please make sure that this is the minimal amount of code we need to replicate the problem - I suspect that not all of this code is actually relevant to the issue but it's hard to tell without the exception details.

Comment: Try with,

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: @hoomi yes, it is returning a string.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Sir, the thing is it's not giving me an exception instead i display it in a TOAST and the "com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)"

Comment: @DaminiMehra I already have that in my manifest.

Comment: @EugeneSantos java.net.SocketException **is** an exception so I'm not sure what you mean about it not giving you an exception. Please post details.